# how to understand the zero vol condition in Heston stochastic vol model

Tags: pricing, heston, call

I can't understand one of the boundary conditions in Heston's model:
$$c(t,s,0) = (s-e^{-r(T-t)}K)^+$$
Why the current vol is zero can deduce such result. here $c(t,s,v)$ $s$ is current price and $v$ is current vol.

Comment: Do you have a reference because I fail to see how this holds as such.

Comment: I believe the question refers to the lower bound of a call option, its intrinsic value.

Comment: @Quantuple @ Freddorick Jan Shreve's book `Stochastic Calculus for finance II` page289, how does current zero vol influence the whole process? Note that it is just zero vol currently, not always zero.